# Wifi module for arduino shield

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, wifi

Recently I bought a [B006RATC2E](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006RATC2E) wireless shield for my Arduino One, but didn't notice that I had to buy a wifi module as well to let it work (bad surprise as the shield already cost me $30 + travel expenses to CR). Could someone be so kind to suggest me some compatible wifi modules for the shield?

I'm kind of newbie in this and when I search specs for Adafruit and XBee modules, the documentation is not explicit about the compatibility with Arduino shields, so I'm stuck.

I don't want to buy components that would't work together (my budget is limited). Is [XBee XB24](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007R9U1QA) a good module for the shield? Any other alternative?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless doesn't necessarily mean it's WiFi.
You should get an XBee module that explicitly states that it's a WiFi module.

For a cheaper alternative you can check ESP8266 WiFi modules, which you can get for $5.

Comment: That definitely helped me, along with this tutorial: http://www.cse.dmu.ac.uk/~sexton/ESP8266, thanks gre_gor! And the best, I don't need a wireless shield to get WiFi